# Map <M-h> to gT / <M-l> to gt

Tags: firefox, pentadactyl

I tried mapping `<M-h>` to go back a tab and `<M-l>` to go right a tab.

Contents of `.pentadactylrc`:

```
nmap <M-h> gT
nmap <M-l> gt
```

It doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Do any key-mappings using the Windows key work for you? I tried `nmap <M-j>`, and FF acted as if I had just pressed `j`, with no Windows key at all.

Comment: @Lemur `meta` is the `alt` key. I'm not actually sure if you can use the windows key in vim/emacs/pentadactyl. As far as I know it's typically called the "super" key.

Comment: Interesting. The Pentadactyl docs distinguish between Alt and the Meta key. See `:help key-notation` (which I'm sure you've done), where it says: "`<M-␣>`: The meta key, windows key, or command key."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the "Alt" key, try `<A-h>`, instead.

```
nmap <A-h> gT
```

Pentadactyl distinguishes between Alt and the Meta key. See `:help key-notation`, where it says:

- `<A-␣>`: The alt key
- `<M-␣>`: The meta key, windows key, or command key.

As your comment says, Pentadactyl doesn't seem to recognize the Windows key at all. After `nmap <M-j> gT`, penta behaves as if I've only pressed `j`.

Comment: Huh, it seems like pentadactyl deviates from vim/emacs terminology. `alt` is normally synonymous with `meta` and the windows key is typically referred to as `super`. `:help key-notation` suggests that my original mapping should work with the windows key which it doesn't. I'm on ubuntu which as far as I know does not enable the windows key by default which explains the peculiarity.

Comment: @deadghost In X11 `Meta` is not a synonym for `Alt`. They have different keycodes. So Vim traditional terminology is a bit confusing nowadays. Try `$ xmodmap` to see which modifiers are synonymous on your system and `$ xev` to see where your hardware keys are mapped.